# .NET 7 TimeOnly data type not compatible with timestamp without time zone in postgres

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

When calling `.ToList()` on an entity in the DB I get:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Ticks must be between 0 and and TimeOnly.MaxValue.Ticks. Arg_ParamName_Name'
```

The data model has two properties that are of type TimeOnly.

In the database, one of the record's end time is `24:00:00.000` but because the ticks are all zero, postgres removes the ticks.

When .NET puts the data into the model (in which there are two properties of type TimeOnly (that require ticks)) it throws an error.

When I change all times to include ticks that are not `.000`, the error does not throw.

Model:

```
public partial class Shift
{
    public TimeOnly Start { get; set; }

    public TimeOnly End { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this data in the database such that it is compatible with the TimeOnly data type? Or is the issue somewhere else?

According to postgres's documentation, Time without timezone maps to TimeOnly in .NET 7.

Postgres version: 12.8

.NET 7

Comment: `24:00:00` is out of range for a `TimeOnly`, with or without fractional seconds (note: these are not called "ticks", that's the absolute value of the thing in 100-ns intervals), so if it doesn't throw an error it's interesting to know what it actually produces. A `TimeSpan` would be able to hold it, and you could convert this (with a check) to a `TimeOnly` in another property. Or filter the value proactively in a query or through a view, though that's a bit less elegant.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, you pointed out that 24:00:00 was out of range, which was the issue all along. 

The reason it worked with nanoseconds was that I changed it to 23:59:59.001 - within range for TimeOnly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not the lack of nanoseconds on the end of the time without time zone value.

The issue was that one of the values was out of range for the TimeOnly type - `24:00:00`.

I changed this value to `00:00:00` and this fixed it.